Build the ios Messages Chat Bubble(with bottom right and left tail ) in Android
I want to build the iOS-like Messages chat bubble in Android using the custom view class this is the code that I use to create the rounded corner rectangle and it will be based on the height and weight it will decide the corner radius of all sides.
This rounder corner rectangle refers to This. Then I will modify some.
In this I want to add the tail at the bottom right side and bottom left side based on the use requirement so can anyone help me to complete this iOS-like Messages chat bubble::
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Path;
    import android.graphics.RectF;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    
    import org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract;
    
    public class Bubble extends View {
    
        private Paint paint;
        private Path path;
    
        public Bubble(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init();
        }
    
        public Bubble(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init();
        }
    
        public Bubble(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            init();
        }
    
        public Bubble(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
            init();
        }
    
        private void init() {

            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    
            RectF rect = new RectF(50f, 50f, 200f, 100f);
            path = getPathOfRoundedRectF(rect, 50f);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
    
        @NonNull
        public static Path getPathOfRoundedRectF(
                @NonNull RectF rect,
                float radius
        ) {
            float width = rect.right - rect.left;
            float height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
            float maxRadius = Math.min(width / 2, height / 2);
    
            float finalRadius = Math.min(radius, maxRadius);
    
            Path path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(rect.left + finalRadius, rect.top);
    
            // Top border
            path.lineTo(rect.right - finalRadius, rect.top);
    
            // Top-right corner
            path.arcTo(
                    new RectF(
                            rect.right - finalRadius * 2,
                            rect.top,
                            rect.right,
                            rect.top + finalRadius * 2
                    ), -90f, 90f
            );
    
            // Right border
            path.lineTo(rect.right, rect.bottom - finalRadius);
    
            // Bottom-right corner
            path.arcTo(
                    new RectF(
                            rect.right - finalRadius * 2,
                            rect.bottom - finalRadius * 2,
                            rect.right,
                            rect.bottom
                    ), 0f, 90f
            );
    
            // Bottom border
            path.lineTo(rect.left + finalRadius, rect.bottom);
    
            // Bottom-left corner
            path.arcTo(
                    new RectF(
                            rect.left,
                            rect.bottom - finalRadius * 2,
                            rect.left + finalRadius * 2,
                            rect.bottom
                    ), 90f, 90f
            );
    
            // Left border
            path.lineTo(rect.left, rect.top + finalRadius);
    
            // Top-left corner
            path.arcTo(
                    new RectF(
                            rect.left,
                            rect.top,
                            rect.left + finalRadius * 2,
                            rect.top + finalRadius * 2
                    ), 180f, 90f
            );
    
            path.close();
    
            return path;
        }
}


I Want this type of Output:
Chat Bubble look like
I want the best solution code I want to add the tail at the bottom right side and bottom left side based on the use requirement so can anyone help me to complete this iOS-like Messages chat bubble?

No Need Custom View
bg_sender.xml : This drawable defines a background with a solid color and rounded corners for the sender’s message. It uses black for the background with varied corner radius.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>

    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="24dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="24dp"/>

</shape>

item_sender.xml: This layout defines how a sender’s message is displayed. It uses a LinearLayout with the bg_sender drawable as the background. It contains two TextView elements: one for the message text and one for the date.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_sender"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Receiver Message"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Mar 10,2016 6:00 PM" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

item_receiver.xml : This layout defines how a receiver’s message is displayed. It uses a LinearLayout with the bg_receiver drawable as the background. It contains two TextView elements: one for the message text and one for the date.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginVertical="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_receiver"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Receiver Message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Mar 10,2016 6:00 PM" />

</LinearLayout>

bg_receiver.xml: This drawable defines the background for the receiver’s message with a white solid color and different rounded corner radii compared to the sender’s background.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="24dp"
        android:topRightRadius="24dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"/>

</shape>

just this item_receiver.xml and item_sender.xml layout add in recycler view


This is not a correct answer I want to build a custom chat bubble with view class in Java
